# find the currently executed jar file name

Tags: java, command-line, jar, parameters

Whenever a jar file is executed in command-line , only the parameters are passed to the main method. How do I find the currently executed Jar file's name?

eg:

```
java -jar myjar.jar arg1 arg2
```

if I wish to get the name of the jar file "myjar.jar", I'm hitting a dead end.

I could hardcode the Jar file name in the code to process it. but, anyone could rename the Jar file before executing it. that defeats the purpose...

Comment: What do you need to know this for?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, might be for many reasons... one particular reason is **self destruction** (one time use jar)

Comment: Windows may not allow you to remove a jar in use.  But if that is your usecase look into java webstart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resource access to try to find the jar

```
YourApplication.class.getResource("/some-resource-in-the-jar.properties")
```

The result could be like this

```
jar:file:/C:/my-project/target/my-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/some-resource-in-the-jar.properties
```

And you can get the jar file name from the resource. In case of running from classes in a dir the jar is empty. You will have just `file:/...`

Comment: I tried `<APPCLASSNAME>.class.getResource("/<internal jar file>.jar")` but the result is `rsrc:<internal jar file>.jar`. I'll try adding a properties file and check out your theory.

Comment: Of course you cannot get resource jar from a jar. A properties file is or you can try to get .class file

Comment: I included a properties file and now I get `rsrc:<resourcefile>.properties`

Comment: Could you add .toString() for the resource?

Comment: I did use it inside `System.out.println()` so it should've automatically called the `toString()` method... I'll try that too

Comment: no use... the same thing... I'll try the available methods in the resource... Hope I get something useful...

Comment: I've been using JDK 1.8 for compilation and execution... Is it that the JAR Resource Specifications been revised in JDK 1.8. I wonder?

Comment: I tried it with JDK 1.8 and my output was `jar:file:/... path .jar!xxx.properties`. may be you run it just from classes? without packing to jar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143502/discussion-between-crystal-paladin-and-stanislavl).